# Safari browser width while zoom out (ctrl -) is not changing css

Tags: css

In Safari 5.1.7 while zoom out (<kbd>ctrl -</kbd>) windows width are changing but in media queries its not effecting, its taking the windows normal width. I added

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

```css
@media (min-device-width:1023px) and (max-device-width:1365px){
    .asset, .fade{margin-left:80px;}
}
@media (min-device-width:1365px) and (max-device-width:1400px){
    .asset, .fade{margin-left:-92px;}
}
@media (min-device-width:1401px) and (max-device-width:1800px){
    .asset, .fade{margin-left:-250px;}
}
@media (min-device-width:1801x) and (max-device-width:2500px){
    .asset, .fade{margin-left:-3sss50px;}
}
@media (min-device-width:2501px) and (max-device-width:3500px){
    .asset, .fade{margin-left:-700px; border:1px solid red !important}
}
@media screen and (min-device-width:1901px) and (max-device-width:2500px){
    .asset, .fade{margin-left:-350px;}
}
@media screen and (min-device-width:3501px) and (max-device-width:5000px){
    .asset, .fade{margin-left:-1350px;}
}


@media all and (min-device-width:1801x) and (max-device-width:2500px){
    .asset, .fade{margin-left:-3sss50px;}
}
@media all and (min-device-width:2501px) and (max-device-width:3500px){
    .asset, .fade{margin-left:-700px; border:1px solid red !important}
}
```